# Probably segmentation fault n>150 000 wtih vector

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

```
int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);

    cin>>n;
    vector<vector<bool> > tab (n+1, vector<bool>(n+1));
    vector<unsigned short int >wifi (n+1);    
    int  z=0;
    x=1;
    do{    
        cin>>a>>b;
        tab[a][b]=1;
        tab[b][a]=1;
        x++;    
    }while(x!=n);
}
```

Hi, I still have a problem, the program has stopped working results greater than 150 000 even though they changed it to vector. I present the code in a nutshell.

Comment: This is not a [mcve], please edit your question. For example, what are `n`, `a`, `b`? What are the input values we have to enter to reproduce the problem? And what is this program supposed to do?

Comment: I wrote that this is part of the program, the output is n <= 200000. This piece has just entered, the path graph.

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is you're running out of memory *or* not checking the input values enough!

Change `[i]`
 to `.at(i)` and make sure the indices are valid:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3193a4c0db52cca9)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);

    size_t n;
    if (std::cin >> n)
    {
        std::cout << "n = " << n << "\n";

        std::vector<std::vector<bool> > tab(n + 1, std::vector<bool>(n + 1));
        std::vector<unsigned short int> wifi(n + 1);

        std::cout << "allocated, reading\n";

        size_t a, b;
        for (size_t m = n; m && std::cin >> a >> b; --m)
        {
            tab.at(a%n).at(b%n) = 1;
            tab.at(b%n).at(a%n) = 1;
            if (m%1000==1) std::cout << "." << std::flush;
        }
    }
}
```

My PC has no trouble even for 250,000 rows.

Now, consider using `dynamic_bitset` or `boost::icl::interval_set` instead. Consider using parallell BGL for distributed AdjacencyMatrix graphs.

Consider `AdjacencyLists` or `EdgeList` if the matrix is sparse.

Comment: Strange, because for me is the same.

Comment: @xodos making it likely you ran out of memory on your system. Can you share the input file? Is it on an online programming challenge?